# cannot access database from multiple unit tests

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I had the connection string and a bunch of my unit tests using it in order to test the logic of some class which was applying some CRUD operations to it. So I was passing it as a private constant field in test class and sharing it to my tests. Everything worked perfectly fine!

But then I realized I have to do it as integration testing. So I've decided to use static helper class to create database via session for me tests to work with it and then drop.

The class is the following:

```
public static class LocalDB
{
    public const string DB_DIRECTORY = "Data";

    public static string GetLocalDB(string dbName, bool deleteIfExists = false)
    {
        try
        {
            var outputFolder = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), DB_DIRECTORY);
            var mdfFilename = dbName + ".mdf";
            var dbFileName = Path.Combine(outputFolder, mdfFilename);
            var logFileName = Path.Combine(outputFolder, $"{dbName}_log.ldf");

            if (!Directory.Exists(outputFolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder);
            }

            if (File.Exists(dbFileName) && deleteIfExists)
            {
                if (File.Exists(logFileName)) File.Delete(logFileName);
                File.Delete(dbFileName);
                CreateDatabase(dbName, dbFileName);
            }

            else if (!File.Exists(dbFileName))
            {
                CreateDatabase(dbName, dbFileName);
            }

            var connectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDBFileName={1};Initial Catalog={0};Integrated Security=True;", dbName, dbFileName);

            CreateTable(connectionString, "Cpa", dbName);

            return connectionString;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static bool CreateDatabase(string dbName, string dbFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

                DetachDatabase(dbName);

                cmd.CommandText = string.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0} ON (NAME = N'{0}', FILENAME = '{1}')", dbName, dbFileName);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.Dispose();
            }

            return File.Exists(dbFileName);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static bool DetachDatabase(string dbName)
    {
        try
        {
            var connectionString = $@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = $"exec sp_detach_db '{dbName}'";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static bool CreateTable(string connectionString, string tableName, string dbName)
    {
        connectionString = connectionString.Replace("master", dbName);
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var createTableQuery = $@"CREATE TABLE {tableName}(
                                            CrmId nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
                                            Service nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
                                            RecurringReference nvarchar(50),
                                            ExpiryDate datetime,
                                            CardNumber nvarchar(50),
                                            Enabled bit,
                                            Brand nvarchar(50),
                                            CpaType nvarchar(50),
                                            Channel nvarchar(50)
                                                                );";

                var command = new SqlCommand(createTableQuery, connection);

                connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Dispose();

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I was calling it's **GetLocalDB** method in my test class' ctor amd initializing field.
After that I've got the following error "the process cannot access the file blah **log.ldf** because it is used by another process"

**!!!** All the tests were using the same connection string, I have no idea what's gone wrong. It can't be the unit tests failure for all I've changed is connection string (was for already existent db -> changed to temporary local (LocalDb class))

Thanks!

Comment: Obligatory: Your not supposed to be unit testing the database you should be mocking it.

Comment: @PaulSwetz that's the point of integration test (I am migrating from AzureStorage to SQL db so It has to be tested)

Comment: Create a proper database instead of using LocalDB and a user-instance database. SQL Server is a database *server*. You won't be using it as an embedded database, especially if you're migrating from cloud storage

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was doing like that. But I was told the point is to create database, test the logic, then drop it. I have no choice.

Comment: LocalDB can only handle a single connection at a time and doing the connection string as a file attach really brings that point to a crashing reality. If you create the local db inside visual studio and use a standard connection string to that you should at least not be exposed to the single user limitation and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

I also used localDb for testing in my web application and had a similar issue. This issue can sometime happen if while debugging you stopped in between or some test ran into any exception and disposing of localdb did not happen properly. If that happens then next time when you start running test it wont create the db(inspite of the check ifdbexists) and run into some exception like you mentioned. To check I added a different name every time we ran a set of tests so that db gets created on start of running test and drops after executing all the tests.As its not ideal to give different name every time , try disposing the localdb in a finally block to make sure it happens even in case of exception